# How addChangeListener works in Facebook React Todo example

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

All:

I am pretty new to React. When I follow its TodoMVC [example](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html), there is one question confuses me so much:

Inside TodoApp component, it registers its handler using TodoStore.addChangeListener:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    TodoStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },
_onChange: function() {
    this.setState(getTodoState());
  }
```

And let CHANGE_EVENT in TodoStore.addChangeListener to trigger that _onChange callback:

```
addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback);
  },
```

What confuses me here is:

1. How "this.on" knows the context of that callback( I mean how does it remember the "this" from _onChange )
2. What if there are multiple TodoApp register their _onChange, so the todoStore will maintain a list of all callbacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It doesn't. the `this` in `this.on` refers to the Store. The provided callback references the `_onChange` function, which uses its own `this`. For it to work it will need to have been bound to the `TodoApp`. I think that example comes from the autobinding era of React. Nowadays you would use a `.bind` either in the `componentDidMount` or the class constructor.

Local Bind

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    TodoStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));
  },
```

OR class bind (the `= () =>` creates an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for the class, closing `this` at the constructor scope)

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
   TodoStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  }

  _onChange = () => {
    this.setState(getTodoState());
  }
}
```

2. Yes. In Flux Stores are [EventEmitters](https://github.com/facebook/emitter), and are designed to have multiple listeners for each event.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, that "this._onChange.bind(this)" is what I think it should be too.  But why the current code without it works too, or Do you mean that code actually not work? I thought if there is no explicit context bind, then when call this.on, the callback will be called with window as its context, right?

Comment: React used to have a feature, on by default, called [Autobind](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/07/02/react-v0-4-autobind-by-default.html), that worked with `React.createClass`, and called `bind` on every function. This code would have worked with that feature.

Comment: thanks. This is amazing, so this means even we define the _onChange: function() {
    this.setState(getTodoState());
  }
like this, but actually this._onChange is something like function() {
    this.setState(getTodoState());
  }.bind(this) ?

Comment: Yes, but this this feature isn't on by default anymore, and isn't even available for the ES6 Class syntax. For ES6 you can either use the arrow syntax I showed above, or call `bind` in the constructor.

Comment: so this code probably written long time ago and not work now if that default feature is not on. Anyway, I get the babsic idea. Thanks, this very helpful